# Was support for PS3 controllers removed in newer kernels?

Tags: linux

Was support for PS3 controllers taken out in 3.12.1 or other recent versions? I can find the option in 3.10.17, it's in Device Drivers -> HID support -> Special HID Drivers, but in 3.12.1 I cannot find it at all, and now my controller doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Support it still there, but the option to enable it is kinda hidden. If you are compiling your own kernel, make sure you have LED Support and LED Class Support enabled (found in the Device Drivers) as well as USB HID support. Then the option for the controller will show back up under Special HID Drivers, as Sony PS2/3 accessories.